# Postgres - Repeating an element N times as array

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

For example, where the element is `'hi'`, and where **N** is `3`, I need a PostgreSQL snippet I can use in a `SELECT` query that returns the following array:

```
['hi', 'hi', 'hi']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `array_agg` with `generate_series`

```
select array_agg(s) from ( values('hi')) as t(s) cross join generate_series(1,3)
```

Generic

```
select array_agg(s) from ( values(:elem)) as t(s) cross join generate_series(1,:n)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ea2b0014d228e38792eefdb43743059f)

Comment: You can simplify it a little: `SELECT array_agg('hi'::text) FROM generate_series(1, 3)`

Answer (score 8):

Postgres provides `array_fill` for this purpose, e.g.:

```
SELECT array_fill('hi'::text, '{3}');
SELECT array_fill('hi'::text, array[3]);
```

The two examples are equivalent but the 2nd form is more convenient if you wish to replace the dimension `3` with a variable.

See also: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Answer (score 0):

**[sql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/30754)**

```
with cte as (
  select 'hi' as rep_word, generate_series(1, 3) as value
)                                         -- ^^^ n = 3
select array(SELECT rep_word::text from cte);
```